# Workaround for Internet Explorer's handling of number input

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm having Internet Explorer difficulties with a number input field. Normally, this field uses the browser's locale to determine what to do with commas. For example in USA commas are simply prevented from being input, while in other countries they may be used to denote a decimal point. This functionality breaks down in IE however, and commas are always treated as a decimal point. This is documented [here](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/html5-input-number-localization.html#impl-notes) however I have not found a working solution to fix this. Any attempt to grab the value and modify it in Javascript fails as the value has already been modified by the browser. Any known solutions to this?

Note: this is a Node project with angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the JavaScript OnKeyPress event to check the pressed key to limit the input, then format the number to only contain a decimal point, code like this:

```
<script>
    function handleKeyPress(e) {
        var newValue = e.target.value + e.key;

        if (
            // It is not a number nor a control key?
            isNaN(newValue) &&
            e.which != 8 && // backspace
            e.which != 17 && // ctrl
            newValue[0] != '-' || // minus
            // It is not a negative value?
            newValue[0] == '-' &&
            newValue[0] == ',' &&
            newValue[0] == '。' &&
            newValue[0] == '，' &&
            isNaN(newValue.slice(1)))

            e.preventDefault(); // Then don't write it!
    }
</script>
<input type="number" onKeyPress="handleKeyPress(event);" />
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

[Note] The above code sample works well on IE 9+.

Comment: Had to modify this for Angular but more or less did the trick. Thanks!